# I have a problem with laravel validation logic when im trying to update my data

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

Hello guys im beginner in laravel and  i need some help.I have a problem with my validation.When i store data in my bootstrap modal everyting is fine but when i press edit button and want to update, the same validation logic applies like when i create.When I want to update, if i don't change the name it won't update because it must be unique.
This is my Department Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'name'=>"required|unique:departments|max:255"
    ]);

    $departmentId = $request->department_id;

    Department::updateOrCreate(
        ['id' => $departmentId],
        ['name' => $request->name, 'description' => $request->description]
    );

    return response()->json(['success'=>'Department saved successfully.']);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... you should look into the `unique` rule, it offers way to ignore records, which is how we are able to use this rule but still update records

Comment: Is it possible to use unique rule in only store method where i use updateOrCreate method?

Comment: you would be dynamically building the rule in this case as it is slightly setup differently for store and update, since you would have to ignore a specific record to do the update and for creating there wouldn't be a record to ignore yet

Comment: Thanks for the answer lagbox.I'm really trying to understand this.When i created store and update methods it worked.My real problem is how to implement this with jquery and ajax because i use jquery datatables and bootstrap modals.

Answer (score 1):

As previously mentioned it would be ideal to have this be 2 different methods, but if you want this in one method you can achieve that. You will need to check if that department id is being passed or not to see if this is an update or create, then adjust the rule based on this. You can try something like this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $unique = \Illuminate\Validation\Rule::unique('deparments');

    if ($request->has('deparment_id')) {
        $unique->ignore($request->department_id);
    }

    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => [
            'required', $unique, 'max:255',
        ],
    ]);

    $departmentId = $request->department_id;

    Department::updateOrCreate(
        ['id' => $departmentId],
        ['name' => $request->name, 'description' => $request->description]
    );

    return response()->json(['success'=>'Department saved successfully.']);
}
```

This assumes the `deparment_id` is only passed for updates.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this :-

```
 $this->validate($request,[
  'name' => 'required|unique:departments|max:255,'. $request->department_id,
]);
```

Comment: but it will be better if you make method for store and method of update

Comment: Thanks Mohamed Ahmed for answer.I created store and update method and worked.Please can you give me some example with jquery ajax because i use jquery datatables and bootstrap modals

Comment: the `max` rule only takes 1 argument, so adding another argument onto it isn't going to do anything ... that would have to be one of the arguments passed to the `unique` rule